Is it possible to include body in list response for Gmail API
I am trying to get body and subject of an email message. Is it possible without having to call another endpoint for each message since that will be a major slowdown.
      const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: "me",
        maxResults: emailCount,
        pageToken: nextPageToken,
        includeSpamTrash: false,
      });

// I have tried 2 functions to extract body but no success

function extractTextFromPayload(
  payload: GmailV1.Schema$MessagePart | undefined
): string | null | undefined {
  if (!payload) {
    return null;
  }

  if (payload.mimeType === "text/plain") {
    const data = payload.body?.data ?? "";
    return Buffer.from(data, "base64").toString("utf8");
  } else if (payload.mimeType === "multipart/alternative") {
    for (const part of payload.parts!) {
      const text = extractTextFromPayload(part);
      if (text) {
        return text;
      }
    }
  }

  return ""; // No text found
}

function parseBody(message: GmailV1.Schema$Message) {
  const payload = message?.payload;

  let messageBody = "";
  const body = payload?.parts ? payload.parts[1].body : payload?.body;

  if (body?.data) {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(body.data, "base64");
    messageBody = buffer.toString("utf-8");
  }

  if (body?.attachmentId) {
    //@ts-ignore
    const textPart = payload?.parts[0]?.parts[1]?.body?.data;
    if (textPart) {
      const buffer = Buffer.from(textPart, "base64");
      messageBody = buffer.toString("utf-8");
    }
  }

  return messageBody;
}

I have found out that gmail supports batch request so if that is a solution is there an example how to do it with googleapis library ?
